# Using LocalStorage to generate links to previously viewed pages

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I'm looking for a way for my website to display a list of links to the last 3 viewed pages, and wonder whether LocalStorage can be used for this purpose.

For example, the pages I'd like stored have a URL which matches the name of the image on the page, and a page title.

Can LocalStorage save these in order (i.e. URL:page1, IMAGE:Page1, TITLE:PageTitle), and then return their values (for example the last 3) when called in other pages on the website and display as below?

RECENTLY VIEWED PAGES:
Page1
Page2
Page3

I'm not looking for someone to produce the code for me, I just wanted to know whether it was possible.

Comment: I guess you could put information like that inside LocalStorage or in cookies, but only if you are tracking information on your own website.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm thinking something along the lines of on an ecommerce website, where you'll view say, half a dozen product pages, and it then displays these products on future pages. That's probably the best example I can think of if that makes sense?

Comment: As mentioned, LocalStorage would work, so would Cookies, so would `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the codebase you are using you could store those in the Session data of the Server Language or you could store them on the parent $scope on the client-side. However, you absolutely can store that information in the local storage of the browser if you want.

Comment: Ah, brilliant, thanks. I don't have server side access so this seems the simplest solution!

Comment: Great, let me know if you have any more questions along the way. More than happy to help. Happy coding!!